# Scrolling the container div over multiple times

Tags: javascript, css, html, containers

I have a page and I wanted to scroll over the data inside of a container like here: http://jsfiddle.net/pXy2C/.

I created columns of text next to each other that I can scroll over using multiple divs. 
Now... in each of those divs, I want to create a button that scrolls the container over to the next div or the previous div. The problem with the jsfiddle example above, it only rolls over the first and last 200px. Is there a way I can take an offset to do what I need to do?

My attempt is here http://jsfiddle.net/3xgSX/, but I'll paste it below as well.

Thanks for any help.

CSS:

```
#container{
width:1000px;
height:500px;
overflow:hidden;
Position:relative;border:1px #000 solid;
}

#contents{
width:1000px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!--Column 1--> 
<div style='float:left; width:150px'>
Put your content here...
<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>
</div><!--end div colomn 1-->


 <!--Column 2-->    
 <div style='float:left; width:150px; margin-left:300px'>
Put another content here...
<br>
<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>

</div><!--End div column2-->



 </div><!--End div "contents"-->
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
$("#right").click(function(){
    $("#contents").animate({left:'-200px'},500);
    $("#container").animate({'margin-left':'200px'},500);
});
$("#left").click(function(){
    $("#contents").animate({left:'0px'},500);
     $("#container").animate({'margin-left':'0px'},500);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, bear with me, there were a number of issues that need to be addressed here so I'm going to go into a bit of detail.

### CSS

To get the same effect as the model fiddle mentioned in the question, `#containers` must have a width equal to your columns. `#contents` must then have a width equal to the width of `#containers` multiplied by the number of columns (three for the sake of this example). `.col` will replace the inline CSS in your original code.

```css
#contents {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
#container {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
#container, .col {
    width: 200px;
}
.col {
    float: left;
}
```

### HTML

Any given `id` can only be used once so I've changed the `#right` and `#left` on the `button` elements to `.right` and `.left`. I've also added a third column as your question was specifically asking about how to apply this general technique to more than two columns.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="contents">

<!--Column 1--> 
<div class="col">
    <p>Put your content here...</p>
    <button class="left">Left</button>
    <button class="right">right</button>
</div><!--end div colomn 1-->


<!--Column 2--> 
<div class="col">
    <p>Put another content here...</p>
    <button class="left">Left</button>
    <button class="right">right</button>
</div><!--End div column2-->


<!--Column 3--> 
<div class="col">
    <p>Put another content here...</p>
    <button class="left">Left</button>
    <button class="right">right</button>
</div><!--End div column3-->



    </div><!--End div "contents"-->
</div><!--End div container-->
```

### JavaScript

To get the `.animate()` jQuery method working the way you want, you have to use relative property values (see the [`.animate()` API page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties) for more information). In order to keep `#container` from sliding off of the columns, I've made a simple function, `getOffset()`, and checked it against the boundaries of `#contents`.

You should also hardcode as few values as possible into the JS and instead read them from the DOM, as I have here with `colwidth` and `contwidth`.

```js
var colwidth = $('#container').width(),
    contwidth = $('#contents').width(),
    getOffset = function() {
        return parseInt($('#container').css('margin-left'));
    };

$(".left").click(function(){
    if (getOffset() === 0) return false;

    $("#contents").animate({left: '+=' + colwidth},500);
    $("#container").animate({'margin-left': '-=' + colwidth},500);
});
$(".right").click(function(){
    if (getOffset() === contwidth - colwidth) return false;

    $("#contents").animate({left: '-=' + colwidth},500);
    $("#container").animate({'margin-left': '+=' + colwidth},500);
});
```

There is probably a more elegant solution if you keep working on it but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: This.is.wonderful. Thank you for explaining everything do thoroughly. I am pretty much a beginner and this is the first "big" project that I have tried to do. I appreciate the help :D